# View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: app_calculation

Tags: python-3.x, flask, post, get

I had a problem when running a web application, I think I entered all the correct path of the folder where the folder with the prediction, but gives an error, how to fix it does not prompt ?

```
# Создаем пользовательское приложение для прогнозирования "соотношения матрица-наполнитель"
# Импортируем необходимые библиотеки для нашего приложения
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)`
```

```
# Загружаем модель и определяем параметры функции  -  будущие входы для модели (всего 12 параметров)

def set_params(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8, param9, param10, param11, param12):

    model = keras.models.load_model("D:/Авито/App/k_m/" )
    prediction = model.predict([param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8, param9, param10, param11, param12])

    return prediction[0][0]
```

```
@app.route('/', methods=['post', 'get'])

def app_calculation():
    param_lst = []
    message = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
       # получим данные из наших форм и кладем их в список, который затем передадим функции set_params
        for i in range(1,13,1):
            param = request.form.get(f'param{i}')
            param_lst.append(float(param))
            
        message = set_params(*param_lst)

    # указываем шаблон и прототип сайта для вывода    
    return render_template("D:/Авито/App/Прогнозы/index.html", message=message) 

# Запускаем приложение  
app.run()
```

`

Tried to use one query at a time, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The error means you have the function name `app_calculation` repeated in your application i.e. you have attached the same function name to more than 1 route(they can only be used once).